# Weird situation with twitter4j in Windows

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have a really weird problem with twitter4j library
When I run my program, I have below lines on my eclipse console, and that's all
no exceptions, no result, it is just stuck forever:

```
[Tue Jul 28 10:39:49 KST 2015]Establishing connection.
[Tue Jul 28 10:39:52 KST 2015]Connection established.
[Tue Jul 28 10:39:52 KST 2015]Receiving status stream.
```

> (I have only one instance of twitter app running on my account).
>   Same code is running perfectly on my Mac, but my Mac and Windows are on the same network.

**here is my code:**

```
public class TFireHouse {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    confBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);

    confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey("************************");
    confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(***********************");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken("***********************");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("**********************");    


    TwitterStream tweetStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(confBuilder.build()).getInstance();

    StatusListener statusListener = new StatusListener() {

        String userName;
        String tweet;
        long tweetId;
        HashtagEntity hashtags;
        String timestamp;
        String profileLocation;
        int retweetCount;
        StringBuffer sb = null;

        FileManager fileWriter = null;

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {} 
        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {}


        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {

            fileWriter = new FileManager();

            sb         = new StringBuffer();
            User user  = status.getUser();

            userName   = status.getUser().getScreenName();
            tweet      = status.getText();
            tweetId    = status.getId();
            timestamp  = status.getCreatedAt().toString();
            profileLocation = user.getLocation();
            retweetCount = status.getRetweetedStatus().getRetweetCount();


            sb.append("{");
            sb.append("\"tweetId\":"     + "\"" + tweetId    + "\",");
            sb.append("\"userName\":"    + "\"" + userName   + "\",");
            sb.append("\"tweet\":"       + "\"" + tweet      +  "\",");
            sb.append("\"retweetCount\":"       + "\"" + retweetCount      +  "\",");
            sb.append("\"postedTime\":"  + "\"" + timestamp  + "\",");
            sb.append("\"hashtags\":"           + "\""   + hashtags.toString() +  "\",");
            sb.append("\"profileLocation\":"    + "\""   + profileLocation     +  "\"");
            sb.append("}");

            fileWriter.fileWriter(sb);
            System.out.println(sb);

        }

    };

    FilterQuery bbcFilter = new FilterQuery();
    String bbc[] = {"BBC"};
    String lan[] = {"en"};
    bbcFilter.track(bbc).language(lan);
    tweetStream.addListener(statusListener);
    tweetStream.filter(bbcFilter);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to pinpoint the exact line where your Java code is failing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I did, but it tells nothing